# How can I create list from a dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to python, and I want to create a list from a dictionary.

If I had a dictionary declared like this:

```
a = {"e1" : "Hello", "e2" : "Hi"}
```

I would want to get a list like this:

```
a = [["e1", "Hello"], ["e2", "Hi"]]
```

I honestly don't know how I would even start to do this so I don't have any code to help.

Comment: Have you done any *research* to help you figure it out on your own? There are *many* online researches.  A SO question should *not* be your first stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop in the dictionary `.keys()` method like this:

```
a = {"e1" : "Hello", "e2" : "Hi"}

b = []
for key in a.keys():
    b.append([key, a[keys]])
```

Comment: Really, `items()` should be used in cases where both are required.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the keys and values, iterate through `a.items()`
If you want just the keys: `a.keys()`
The values: `a.values()`

```
a = {"e1" : "Hello", "e2" : "Hi"}

b = []
for key, value in a.items():
    b.append([key, value])
```